# flurry to iphone,add details are not opening

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have integrated flurry to my project and add is displaying successfully.but the problem is when i clicked on the add then its coming like "safari can't open the page",i have used below code,please help me where i went wrong or what will i do?.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [FlurryAds setAdDelegate:self];
    [FlurryAds fetchAndDisplayAdForSpace:@"BANNER_MAIN_VIEW" view:self.view size:BANNER_TOP];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Reset delegate
    [FlurryAds removeAdFromSpace:@"BANNER_MAIN_VIEW"];
}
```

and in console i am getting like:

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:[http://itunes.apple.com/app/id505821326?partnerId=30&siteID=PIA/JJ6Lt9U]navigationType:5
```

Comment: Did you go through flurry documentation?

Comment: yes,i have gone through that.

Comment: Hello Murali have you solved this ?